# How to increase request file size in express app

Tags: node.js, express, npm, body-parser

I already run my express app using server.js:
    'use strict';

```
function getEnv() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
        require('./env/prod.json') : require('./env/dev.json');
}

var _ = require('lodash');
var express = require('express');
var status = require('./routes/status');
var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
var env = getEnv();

var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./best-admin'));
app.listen(9000, function() {
    console.log('GUI is available on port 9000...');
});

_.forEach(env.endpoints, function (endpoint) {
    app.use(endpoint.route, proxy(endpoint.address));
    console.log('Set proxy %s to %s', endpoint.route, endpoint.address);
});

var app_backend = express();
app_backend.use('/', status);
app_backend.use(function(req, res) {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, that route doesn't exist. Have a nice day :)");
});
app_backend.listen(9001, function() {
    console.log('GUI backend is listening on port 9001...');
});
```

Then I upload file using 'ng-file-upload' - and **everything works fine**.

**Problem is** when I try upload file which have more than 1MB when my express serwer return error:

> PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

**Question**: How to increase request file size in express app?

**What I tried:**

I traied add:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

But then my backend can not take my file - field "file" is empty, but Request Payload say something else:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryI6qQHASwrdRVhgAG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";      filename="fileName.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml


------WebKitFormBoundaryI6qQHASwrdRVhgAG--
```

Moreover my application started required additional localhost:9000 authentication.

Comment: so many unknowns in the question. What is the nature of the two servers?